# Synology Open VPN Server to Client connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn, synology, vpn-client

I have a 2 sites:

- Synology A (192.168.1.100) - running VPN Server (10.8.0.1)
- Synology B (192.168.2.100) - running VPN Client (connecting with 10.8.0.10)

I'm trying to setup Hyper Backup from **Synology A** (source) to **Synology B** (destination).

I was able to connect using Open VPN from **Synology A** to **Synology B** but I'm not able to setup Hyper Backup from **Synology A** specifying **10.8.0.10** as destination IP.

Firewall is setup as:

on **Synology A**

- ports: all, source 10.8.0.0, protocol: all, action: allow
- ports: all, source 192.168.2.0, protocol: all, action: allow

on **Synology B**

- ports: all, source 10.8.0.0, protocol: all, action: allow
- ports: all, source 192.168.1.0, protocol: all, action: allow

However, I'm still not able to connect. What am I missing?

**Update**:
**Synology B** is setup with Hyper Backup Vault and has pre-existing HB backups and it works when using direct connection (not via VPN). The reason I want to use VPN is to have **Synology B** on **4G** connection and mobile data plans use shared public IPs, therefore I cannot have direct incoming connections, but apparently this is achievable using VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so changing a bit my networks (that probably doesn't matter)

**LAN**

Synology A (192.168.1.100) - running VPN Server (192.168.81.1)

**4G**

Synology B (192.168.2.100) - running VPN Client (connecting with 192.168.81.6)

**Synology A (VPN Server)**

[image]

**Synology B (4G VPN Client)**

I imported openvpn profile.

[image]

Here I have VPN reconnect handling script that runs every 5 minutes:
https://github.com/ianharrier/synology-scripts/blob/master/reconnect-vpn.sh

[image]

So now VPN Server on **Synology A** sees the client connected:

[image]

And so **HyperBackup** can be setup given VPN client's IP address:

[image]

Opening firewall ports wasn't necessary.